# functions from tmap package crashes my R

Tags: r, geospatial, tmap

The following code [crashed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5jU2MG97GH0RE51WDZyd3p3TVk/view?usp=sharing) my R session. I tried it in both RStudio and conda R in Jupyter Notebook:

```
qtm(shp = countries_spdf, fill = "population")
tm_shape(countries_spdf) + tm_fill(col = "population")
```

You can get the dataset from the code below:

```
download.file("http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_1816/datasets/02_countries_spdf.rds","data/02_countries_spdf.rds")
countries_spdf <- readr::read_rds("data/02_countries_spdf.rds")
```

**Error:**

> Assertion failed: (0), function query, file AbstractSTRtree.cpp, line 285.
>       Abort trap: 6

**Environment:**

- Mac OSX 10.10.5
- R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
- conda 4.3.9
- jupyter notebook 4.2.3
- RStudio Version 1.0.44

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the crash. Probably, it is caused by one of the libraries gdal or geos. Does library(sp); plot(countries_spdf) work?

Comment: @MartijnTennekes Yes it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related, but I cannot even get the current version of tmap and tmaptools to load. When I try, it crashes R.

```
> library(tmap)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 4: asNamespace(ns)
 5: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 6: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
 7: asNamespace(ns)
 8: namespaceImportFrom(ns, loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc,     .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]), i[[2L]], from = package)
 9: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
10: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
11: loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
12: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
13: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
14: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
15: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
16: library(tmap)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

I'm running current Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.6) and R 3.4.1. This happens both in RStudio and in the R GUI that comes with R for Mac.